# What is the Relationship between Magnetic Flux density and electric field intensity

Tags: electromagnetism, homework, magnetic-flux, electric-field

I was given this question by a teacher and I have scoured the internet for a formula or solution to this question, all to no avail, the question says
"in a certain region of space, the magnetic field has a value of 1 x 10<sup>-2</sup> T and electric field has a value of 2 x 10<sup>-6</sup>V/m, what is the combined density of the electric and magnetic field. With E<sub>0</sub> and U<sub>0</sub> given below" [image]!

Comment: The is no relationship between static electric and magnetic fields. You're asked to find the density (energy density is the only 'density' that makes sense here) and combine them, ie add them together to get a total energy density.

Comment: Just for information: The SI unit for the permittivity is farads per meter.

Comment: Oh Okay, how exactly do i do that? @ Neil_uk

Comment: The 1st comment is serious. You can calculate separately for the magnetic field and the electric field their energy densities as joules per cubic meter and add them together. End of notification.

Comment: I think the answer should be something in terms of the electromagnetic four-potential or it's exterior derivative, the electromagnetic tensor. This however will move you outside the area of regular electrical engineering, into the realm of Einsteinian relativity.